# My friend's Kubuntu devices suddenly won't boot to my desktop anymore

Tags: kubuntu

On my friend's laptop and on his pc with Kubuntu, it suddenly stopped booting to desktop after he ran out of storage. It would get to the login screen like normal, but when he tries to sign in to his account with wayland it just goes to a black screen. When he tries to sign in with X11, nothing happends.
He can get in to the tty, and we learned it says plasma isn't installed anymore. We uninstalled some things through terminal.
`apt update` gave the error "Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead". `apt upgrade` just says nothing to upgrade or remove.
`sudo apt install kde-plasma-desktop` gave us "Failed to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing" again. And `sudo apt-get update --fix-missing` gave us "Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead" again. apt autoclean and apt-get clean didn't clean anything and I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You've provided few specific details; in particular what Kubuntu release are you asking about. If you lack space in $HOME or your user directory, a GUI login cannot occur, as required *workfiles* will fail at being created; meaning the logged in session cannot start & login loop will occur. I wonder if this was your issue, which you made worse by making changes.. You can login via text terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 for example), erase files & create space then GUI logins may occur, but for us to help with specific details we need to know what OS/release you're using, and actual messages

Comment: You mention "*failed to fetch*" for example, which is the final summary, but the actual KEY error message(s) appeared before that summary detail.. For us to help, we need all key messages (not just final summaries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We uninstalled an app through flatpak using tty, rebooted the computers, and the went to desktop like normal. From there we purged any apps he didn't need to try and prevent this from happening again. This was on Kubuntu 23.04.

Comment: You've answered your own question, so thanks for sharing that answer with others, but I'm sorry but I don't see how this actually answers you question.  *You do realize this is a Q&A site and not a forum, you've posted this as an answer thus it's now a self-answered question. Any additional details/clarifications should be made to the actual question itself*  Either way I'm glad you solved your problem.